# Как привязать пиксель Facebook к кнопке

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api

У меня есть мини ленд в шапке которого находится пиксель Facebook и он собирает информацию вообще обо всем.

А мне нужно чтобы он работал лишь на нажатие кнопок на этой странице.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Загружать сам пиксель из скрипта только по нажатию кнопки, ответ очевиден.

Comment: То есть "повесить" на нажатие кнопки добавление на страницу всего кода пикселя? Или лишь какую-то его часть?